# Admob Banner randomly changing from BANNER to FULL_BANNER size with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, admob, android-jetpack-compose

I am integrating Admob's banners in my app, this app runs both in AndroidTV and Android, where it's running in mobile the dimensions must be `320x50(BANNER)` which is part of the standard sizes in the docs, but it turns of nowhere to `468x60(FULL_BANNER)`, this behavior happens oftentimes when you run the app. I am using Jetpack Compose for this, and the add is placed inside a LazyColumn which is the equivalent to a recycler view

My code for the banner is like this:

```
enum class BannerSize {
    NORMAL,
    RECTANGLE;

    internal fun map(): AdSize = when (this) {
        NORMAL -> AdSize.BANNER
        RECTANGLE -> AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE
    }
}



    /*
     This Composable goes inside a lazy column with other composable where I have a 
     when statement, where I look if the index is 0 or 5 which are the specific 
     indexes I want to place the ads.
    */
@Composable
internal fun BannerAd(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    size: BannerSize = BannerSize.NORMAL,
    id: String = "TODO",
    pos: String = "TODO",
    adId: String,
) {
    val isInEditMode = LocalInspectionMode.current
    if (!isInEditMode) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(20.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            AndroidView(
                modifier = modifier
                    .height(size.map().height.dp)
                    .width(size.map().width.dp),
                factory = { context ->
                    Napier.d(
                        tag = "Ads",
                        message = "Creating Ad, id: $id, adId: $adId, pos: $pos, size: $size"
                    )
                    AdView(context).apply {
                        adListener = object : AdListener() {
                            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {
                                Napier.e(tag = "Ads", message = p0.message)
                            }
                        }
                        adSize = size.map()
                        adUnitId = adId
                        loadAd(
                            AdRequest.Builder()
                                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(
                                    AdMobAdapter::class.java,
                                    Bundle().also {
                                        it.putString("pos", pos)
                                    }
                                )
                                .build()
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    } else {
        EditModeText()
    }
}
```

[image]

Has someone encountered something like this while integrating ads with Compose? I've looking for some questions related to this, but I haven't found any

Comment: Seems like a bug, unless there's some other part of the code that modifies the parameter for some reason.

Comment:  ... nothing works

Comment: @MARSK Yeah. I have checked and no, the debugger display the right values but the dimensions change

Comment: File it as a bug on the issue tracker maybe.

Comment: @PabloPantaleon, you okay there buddy?

Comment: Yeah, seems like a it could probably a bug from Compose @MARSK

Comment: Share the link here once you file the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after doing a lot research, turns out it was something related to Android view's lifecycle, to avoid this weird behaviour I did what is in this answer
: [AdManagerAdView not rendering ad image when off screen in LazyColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71681897/admanageradview-not-rendering-ad-image-when-off-screen-in-lazycolumn/71864474#comment127699157_71864474)

We must set the ad during on doOnLayout method, and It will fix this problem for now.